# Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. Log4j2 to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, log4j2, elastic-stack

I am trying to get spark logs to logstash with custom log4j2 properties. My log4j2 properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, server

#We will use socket appender
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender

#Port where socket server will be listening for the log events
log4j.appender.server.Port=5044

log4j.appender.server.encoding=UTF-8

#Defining the layout
log4j.appender.server.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.server.layout.conversionPattern=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir} [%d] %p %m (%c)%n

#Host name or IP address of socket server
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=192.168.85.176

#Define any connection delay before attempting to reconnect
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

Logstash configuration file

```
 input {
  tcp {
    port => 5044
         codec => plain {
               charset => "UTF-8"
     }
   }
}
filter{}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am getting from logstash stdout

```
 "port" => 37438,
    "@timestamp" => 2021-06-15T06:44:57.495Z,
          "host" => "slave1",
       "message" => "threadNameq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\rthrowableInfot\u0000+Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation;xp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001z\u000EjzIt\u00006org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactorypppt\u00006Creating new connection to slave2/192.168.85.177:51795t\u0000\u0016netty-rpc-connection-0pw\u0004\u0000\u0000'\u0010pxy",
      "@version" => "1"
```

I tried several charsets but it doesn't work. Appreciate your help

Comment: can you add `json filter` and see the output? something like this `filter{
  json{
    source => "message"
  }
}`

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment.  I need to read it as a line. I have to apply grok patterns as well.